# Triggering Jenkins Build with a specific label on GitHub

Tags: jenkins, github, github-api

I want to trigger a GitHub job with a specific label on a Pull Request (Let's say "Auto-tests".).

I created a label, set up a Webhook under:

"Let me select individual events" --> Pull Requests

(Pull requests
Pull request opened, closed, reopened, edited, assigned, unassigned, review requested, review request removed, labeled, unlabeled, or synchronized)

But when I apply my custom label on a Pull Request nothing happens.
If I select "Just the push event" and just push code I get the trigger working.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Can you add additional details ? Such as the Jenkins job, your configurations on Github via snapshots, etc... ?
It's very hard to help without additional meta-data....

Comment: Sure, I'd like the webhook to trigger a Jenkins Job that builds an Android application. The webhook should be sent whenever I put a label in the Pull Request page in GitHub. I'd like it to be a specific label but I feel it's not possible without further filtering in Jenkins

Comment: Thanks,this helps. I actually meant for you to update your OP with additional info/snapshots :)

Comment: Please ensure your Payload URL at Webhooks similar like this URL: `http://ci.your-jenkins-server.com/github-webhook/`

Comment: It's correct because the "Just the push" option works fine